# Merge 2 files in one with a customized line in between

Tags: bash, text-processing

I have 2 Files A and B. I want to merge them in File C with a customized line in between.

File A:

```
Hello
```

File B:

```
Hi
```

The merged file should contain:

```
Records in File A is 
Hello
Records in File B is 
Hi
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
for file in fileA fileB; do 
    printf 'Records in %s are\n%s\n' "$file" "$(cat "$file")"
done > fileC
```

Or:

```
for file in fileA fileB; do 
    echo "Records in $file are"; cat "$file"
done > fileC
```

Both produce:

```
Records in fileA are
Hello
Records in fileB are
hi
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for f in A B
do
 (echo "Records in File $f is"; cat "$f" ) >> C
done
```

Comment: newlines missing...